# How to make android to use my subclass of QtActivity instead of the original QtActivity?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I am using Qt 5.2 for Android. I have an application that uses some specific functions written on Java. In Qt 5.1, there was QtActivity.java file, which was created automatically by Qt Creator IDE. So, I just modified its contents and used JNI for calling functions from C++ code. In Qt 5.2, this file is not a part of a project anymore, building project erases any changes in this file.

Now, I am wondering - is there any way to force android to use my own subclass instead of the original one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to manually edit the AndroidManifest.xml file. Change the value of `android:name` in the following:

```
<activity ... android:name="org.qtproject.qt5.android.bindings.QtActivity ...
```

to your package and class name.